# Can't get array of fs.Dirent from fs.readdir

Tags: node.js, fs

I am using node 8.10.0.

`fs.readdir()` returns an array of filenames and child directory names, or  [`fs.Dirents[]`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options).

I can't get that to work. Here's a simple example:

```
console.log(require("fs").readdirSync("/", {withFileTypes:true}));
```

This gives me an array of strings (e.g. `["bin", "mnt", "usr", "var", ...]`), not an array of `fs.Dirent` objects (which is what I want).

How do I get this to work?

Comment: share the output.

Comment: fs.readddir(...) always return array of strings contains the file names.

Comment: for fetching files you have iterate over this array.

Comment: @mehta-rohan No check that link, you can get `fs.Dirent[]`

Comment: checked, I have right the answer

Comment: Have you managed to get this working? I have the same problem using the latest node v11.3.0.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Required functionality is added in: v10.10.0, you have to update node.

Comment: run  `node -v` in cli

Comment: Oh I see now: ["Class: fs.Dirent #Added in: v10.10.0"](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_dirent)

Comment: upgraded to v10.10.0, still get an array of strings

Comment: ...f*ck. what is the legacy way of doing it then? A LOT of stats?

Answer (score 3):

I've hit the same problem and although I have the latest node.js (v10.16 currently) and intellisense in VS Code is consistent with the [online documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback), the run-time reality surprised me. But that is because the code gets executed by node.js v10.2 (inside a VS Code extension).

So on node.js 10.2, this code works for me to get files in a `directory`:

```js
import * as fs from 'fs';
import util = require('util');
export const readdir = util.promisify(fs.readdir);

let fileNames: string[] = await readdir(directory)
    // keep only files, not directories
    .filter(fileName => fs.statSync(path.join(directory, fileName)).isFile());
```

On the latest node.js, the same code could be simplified this way:

```js
let fileEnts: fs.Dirent[] = await fs.promises.readdir(directory, { withFileTypes: true });

let fileNames: string[] = fileEnts
    .filter(fileEnt => fileEnt.isFile())
    .map(fileEnt => fileEnt.name);
```

The code snippets are in Typescript.